# native messaging host chrome-token-signing

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to make an extension that will communicate with a native messaging host chrome-token-signing (https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-signing).
I have installed  extension , but the EXE is not started. I have message log TEST: {"message":"Invalid argument","result":"invalid_argument"}
Do I need to do Something

I have installed the host in the registry like 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\ee.ria.esteid
 and  value  C:\Users\dev\Desktop\chrome-token-signing\host-windows\ee.ria.esteid.json

The native application manifest.json:

```
{

"name": "ee.ria.esteid",

"description": "Give signatures with your eID on the web",

"path": "chrome-token-signing.exe",

"type": "stdio",

"allowed_origins": [

    "chrome-extension://ckjefchnfjhjfedoccjbhjpbncimppeg/"

]

   }
```

manifest.json of extension

```
{

"name": "Token signing",
"version": "0.0.24",
"minimum_chrome_version": "40.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Use your eID smart card on the web",
"icons": {
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*", "file:///*"],
    "exclude_matches": ["*://www.overdrive.com/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
}],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": ["nativeMessaging"],
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "{443830f0-1fff-4f9a-aa1e-444bafbc7319}"
  }
   }
    }
```

background.js

```
      var NO_NATIVE_URL = "https://open-eid.github.io/chrome-token-signing/missing.html";

      var HELLO_URL = "https://open-eid.github.io/chrome-token-signing/hello.html";

      var DEVELOPER_URL = "https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-  signing/wiki/DeveloperTips";

      var NATIVE_HOST = "ee.ria.esteid";

      var K_SRC = "src";
      var K_ORIGIN = "origin";
      var K_NONCE = "nonce";
      var K_RESULT = "result";
      var K_TAB = "tab";
      var K_EXTENSION = "extension";

      // Stores the longrunning ports per tab
      // Used to route all request from a tab to the same host instance
      var ports = {};

      // Probed to false if host component is OK.
       var missing = true;

      console.log("Background page activated");

      // XXX: probe test, because connectNative() does not allow to check the presence
       // of native component for some reason
      typeof chrome.runtime.onStartup !== 'undefined' &&       chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
// Also probed for in onInstalled()
_testNativeComponent().then(function(result) {
    if (result === "ok") {
        missing = false;
    }
});
      });

    // Force kill of native process
   // Becasue Port.disconnect() does not work
   function _killPort(tab) {
if (tab in ports) {
    console.log("KILL " + tab);
    // Force killing with an empty message
    ports[tab].postMessage({});
}
     }

       // Check if native implementation is OK resolves with "ok", "missing" or "forbidden"
      function _testNativeComponent() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(NATIVE_HOST, {}, function(response) {
        if (!response) {
            console.log("TEST: ERROR " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
            // Try to be smart and do some string matching
            var permissions = "Access to the specified native messaging host is forbidden.";
            var missing = "Specified native messaging host not found.";
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError.message === permissions) {
                resolve("forbidden")
            } else if (chrome.runtime.lastError.message === missing) {
                resolve("missing");
            } else {
                resolve("missing");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("TEST: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response["result"] === "invalid_argument") {
                resolve("ok");
            } else {
                resolve("missing"); // TODO: something better here
            }
        }
    });
});
        }

      // When extension is installed, check for native component or direct to helping page
      typeof chrome.runtime.onInstalled !== 'undefined' && chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
if (details.reason === "install" || details.reason === "update") {
    _testNativeComponent().then(function(result) {
            var url = null;
            if (result === "ok" && details.reason === "install") {
                // Also set the flag, onStartup() shall be called only
                // on next startup
                missing = false;
                // TODO: Add back HELLO page on install
                // once there is a nice tutorial
                 url = HELLO_URL;
            } else if (result === "forbidden") {
                url = DEVELOPER_URL;
            } else if (result === "missing"){
                url = NO_NATIVE_URL;
            }
            if (url) {
                chrome.tabs.create({'url': url + "?" + details.reason});
            }
    });
}
     });

   // When message is received from page send it to native
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if(sender.id !== chrome.runtime.id && sender.extensionId !== chrome.runtime.id) {
    console.log('WARNING: Ignoring message not from our extension');
    // Not our extension, do nothing
    return;
    }
if (sender.tab) {
    // Check if page is DONE and close the native component without doing anything else
    if (request["type"] === "DONE") {
        console.log("DONE " + sender.tab.id);
        if (sender.tab.id in ports) {
            // FIXME: would want to use Port.disconnect() here
            _killPort(sender.tab.id);
        } 
    } else {
        request[K_TAB] = sender.tab.id;
        if (missing) {
            _testNativeComponent().then(function(result) {
                if (result === "ok") {
                    missing = false;
                    _forward(request);
                } else {
                    return _fail_with (request, "no_implementation");
                }
            });
        } else {
            // TODO: Check if the URL is in allowed list or not
            // Either way forward to native currently
            _forward(request);
        }
    }
    }
        });

  // Send the message back to the originating tab
  function _reply(tab, msg) {
msg[K_SRC] = "background.js";
msg[K_EXTENSION] = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab, msg);
     }

 // Fail an incoming message if the underlying implementation is not
 // present
 function _fail_with(msg, result) {
var resp = {};
resp[K_NONCE] = msg[K_NONCE];
resp[K_RESULT] = result;
_reply(msg[K_TAB], resp);
    }

  // Forward a message to the native component
     function _forward(message) {
var tabid = message[K_TAB];
console.log("SEND " + tabid + ": " + JSON.stringify(message));
// Open a port if necessary
if(!ports[tabid]) {
    // For some reason there does not seem to be a way to detect missing components from longrunning ports
    // So we probe before opening a new port.
    console.log("OPEN " + tabid + ": " + NATIVE_HOST);
    // create a new port
    var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(NATIVE_HOST);
    // XXX: does not indicate anything for some reason.
    if (!port) {
        console.log("OPEN ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
    }
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log("RECV "+tabid+": " + JSON.stringify(response));
            _reply(tabid, response);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR "+tabid+": " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
            _fail_with(message, "technical_error");
        }
    });
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        console.log("QUIT " + tabid);
        delete ports[tabid];
        // TODO: reject all pending promises for tab, if any
    });
    ports[tabid] = port;
    ports[tabid].postMessage(message);
} else {
    // Port already open
    ports[tabid].postMessage(message);
   }
         }
```

Comment: So you get the "Invalid argument" logged when using chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage? In the branch where 'response' argument from the callback is NOT false/ 0, correct? If so, that branch is for when the response is valid, and the native app simply informs you that you gave it invalid arguments. Are you sure the native app is not started?

Comment: @kundrata  , after building the project I have an excutable file "chrome token signing.exe" when I try to run it, I have an empty cmd window. means that  app is started correctly???

Comment: When chrome starts it as a native app, the console will not appear. Its' output stream will be 'linked' to the chrome app, not a console window.

Comment: You can check if the program starts by adding UAC request when it starts. Right click chrome-token-signing.exe, choose Properties, go to Compatibility tab, and check the box the says "Run this program as an administrator". If anyone(including chrome.exe) tries to execute the app, an UAC request will appear.

Comment: @kundrata I do like you say and I have   this log message : TEST: ERROR {"message":"Error when communicating with the native messaging host."} when I update extension in the browser

Comment: That's good that the error message changed. Did you get a windows prompt asking you for admin permissions?

Comment: yes , i get it.

Comment: Ok that means the native app EXE is started. You need to give it good arguments here: "chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(NATIVE_HOST, {}" between the braces. Now you need to check what arguments are valid for it and include them in your code, like: "chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(NATIVE_HOST, {"some_valid_argument"}"

Comment: can you give me an exemple of a valid argument, what type value???? I try with a simple string but I have an  SyntaxError

Comment: It depends on the native app exe. Where did you get it from? maybe I can find something there.

Comment: Nvm, I just saw the link. Gonna check it out.

Comment: So is everything working like you expected? If not, try this link https://open-eid.github.io/chrome-token-signing/hello.html, and click on the link in there, see what happens.

Comment: this link return  Error 404 File not found

Comment: This is the only guide I could find https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-signing/wiki/Token-Support. The app seems to be working, but I'm not familiar with eCards and don't know how that process works. I believe there should be a button so that you can use the app to ssign a document with eCard, but there is none in the extension. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: thanks a lot for  your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native app is started and it replies to you that the arguments you give it are invalid.

You need to check with native app documentation and see what arguments are valid for that particular app and use them in the messages you send it from the extension. Your request will look like:

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(NATIVE_HOST, {text: "some_valid_argument"}, function(response){
........
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply it ok now  I don't have a message in console log